# node.js, MySQL, JSON, DB connection and CRUD

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, crud, mean

With node.js, I am trying to read and write to a MySQL database from JSON data.

I can get data from db with:

```
app.get('/fetchdata',function(req,res) {
    var data = {
        "Data":""
    };

    connection.query("SELECT * from stuff",function(err, rows, fields){
        if(rows.length != 0){
            data["Data"] = rows;
            res.json(data);
        }else{
            data["Data"] = 'No data Found..';
            res.json(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And I'm trying to write to db with:

```
app.post('/fetchdata',function(req,res) {
    var ssn = req.body.Ssn;
    var name = req.body.Name;
    var password = req.body.Password;
    var category = req.body.Category;
    var address = req.body.Address;
    var phone = req.body.Phone;
    var bankaccount = req.body.Bankaccount;
    connection.query("INSERT INTO stuff (Ssn, Name, Password, Category, Address, Phone, Bankaccount) VALUES("+ ssn +", "+ name +", "+ password +", "+ category +","+ address +","+ phone +", "+ bankaccount +")"), function(req) {
        req.json(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what isn't working?  Are you getting any errors?